# How to perform curl command to Secured ElasticSearch (ElasticSearch running in Openshift namespace openshift-logging)

Tags: elasticsearch, ssl, curl, https, openshift

I have installed ElasticSearch in openshift-logging namespace in my openshift cluster.
I'm able to perform curl to elasticsearch using bearer token, now I want to perform curl to ElasticSearch using TLS certs.

**CURL working with oc exec**

`oc exec elasticsearch-cdm -- curl -tlsv1.2 --insecure -H "Authorization: Bearer $(token)" "https://172.30.245.25:9200/_cat/health"`

**CURL working with elasticsearch service route using bearer token**

`curl -tlsv1.2 --cacert -H "Authorization: Bearer $(token)" https://$(esRoutes)/_cat/health`

Now I want to perform curl using TLS certification, I have extracted secrets from running elasticsearch cluster and included the cert and key filename below,

**Certs and Keys:**

`admin-ca admin-cert admin-key elasticsearch.crt elasticsearch.key logging-es.crt logging-es.key`

How to perform CURL to running ElasticSearch (in openshift namespace opernshift-logging) using certs ?.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this is what you are looking for:

```
oc exec -n openshift-logging logging-es-data-master-xxxxx-x-xxxxx -- curl -tls1.2 -s -k --cert /etc/elasticsearch/secret/admin-cert   --key /etc/elasticsearch/secret/admin-key https://localhost:9200/_cat/health

optional
oc exec -n openshift-logging logging-es-data-master-xxxxx-x-xxxxx -- curl -tls1.2 -s -k --cert /etc/elasticsearch/secret/admin-cert   --key /etc/elasticsearch/secret/admin-key https://localhost:9200/_cat/thread_pool?v

es-util version
oc exec -n openshift-logging logging-es-data-master-xxxxx-x-xxxxx -c elasticsearch -- es_util --query=_cluster/health?pretty=true
```